# how to make a download button in c# asp.net? with a query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

well i need to have a download button ... i am going to get the url where the file is for example

select url from table where id=3;

(it is going to return "c:/my documents/images/file.xxx);

now i have a button for download it?
how do i download this file than if found in that url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is creat a dropdown and have a button next to it.. You can fill the dropdown based on your query.. On the button click you can send the file as a stream to respone.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=downloadedFile.JPG");
Response.TransmitFile( @"c:/my documents/images/file.xxx" );
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // set content type of file by using it's extension
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg"); // make the save as dialog appear with a friendly file name
Response.TransmitFile( "c:/my documents/images/file.xxx" ); // do the hard stuff!
Response.End();
```

Taken from [Rick Strahl's Weblog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-doc";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.doc");
Response.TransmitFile( "c:/my documents/docs/file.doc" );
Response.End();
```